# Using other web app App_GlobalResources resorces asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I cant't figure out how can i use other web app App_GlobalResources resources file in my webapp

both are in same server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Resources stored in `App_GlobalResources` could be used only by the web application that hosts them and by no other web application.